# API call to /comments/{id}/flags/options route is aborted

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

When I make a call to [`/comments/{id}/flags/options`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comment-flag-options), I receive connection time out errors. Firebug shows that the status is aborted:

[image: Aborted call]

And Firefox itself says

```
The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

An example comment I was trying to retrieve flagging options for is:

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/37994626/flags/options/?access_token=<<VALIDTOKEN>>&site=stackoverflow&filter=default&key=<<VALIDKEY>>`

The access_token is valid, and has write access. The key is also valid.

I am also able to replicate the behavior on the API documentation page, though it says "Invalid JSON returned". Could this be related to the [BOM error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235000/186281) I reported (though has been fixed)?

[image: Online test]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a serialization error resolved by Kevin Montrose on Friday (his day off).

Next time you see him, give him crap for sucking at vacation, like the rest of us.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this has been resolved. I tested it about 15 minutes before posting this answer and it functioned as expected.

Thank you to the mysterious developer that fixed it.